# Mame "Required rom/disk images for the selected system are missing or incorrect"

Tags: mame

I downloaded a ROM file from a Google search, and then I downloaded the latest version of Mame,  "mame0231b_64bit.exe". Now, when I tried to run it, I got "Required rom/disk images for the selected system are missing or incorrect". What is wrong? The message is ambiguous to me. Is the ROM file corrupt or, are some additional files for Mame missing, or are the settings incorrect?

[image]

Comment: This is usually because the version rom you are using is not made for the version mame you are using. Either try an older version of mame, search for your game’s romset for whatever version mame you use or track down the missing files individually using google and add them to the rom you have.

Comment: But looking at your pic, you are trying to run altered beast with mame. Is that the arcade version, or the genesis? If it’s the arcade version, it’s probably  what I said in my other comment. If it’s the genesis version, well, that’s why :)

Comment: @RonKyle Damn. You were right. I checked the website where I downloaded the ROM from and in their download page, MAMEUI 0.186 version was listed. So, on the official Mame page, I downloaded `mame0186b_64bit.exe`, and the same ROM worked without a problem. This is strange. Why don't the developers of Mame maintain backward compatibilities?

Comment: @RonKyle I have tested previous versions of Mame to see when this problem started to happen. It happened with version 0.227. I browsed its change log and found: "segas16b.cpp: verified 315-5298 dump and added it to all ROM boards which use it (171-5797, 171-5521, 171-5704)". That is the same numbers I saw in the error message. This is probably a bug.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it has something to do with newer versions of mame requiring a better dump of the rom because of features added to mame. Although that’s just what what somebody said, I didn’t really look into it. I just always run into the problem with Galaga. For the longest time I thought all the Galaga roms floating around were incomplete or something. It’s definitely not a bug, though;